# restTemplate.getForEntity when reading data that contains a list with single element gives Exception

Tags: java, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I have a Detail object that has a property of object of type Product. Product has a property called xxx which is an arraylist. I do a GET on the URL with postman and the result looks like:

```
"Product": {
    "id": "2",
    "xxx": [
        "price": "50"
      },
      {
        "price": "60"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This result is good. But, in my Spring project, when I do a get Using RestTemplate as:

```
  restTemplate.getForEntity("someurl", Detail.class).getBody();
```

I get correct results when xxx list contains 2 or more element.
  However, when there is only element in this list, I get an error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

  How do I fix this issue that I am facing with my call to restTemplate.getForEntity as above?
```

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect, looks like manually edited before posting.

Comment: Can you provide unedited + JSON which fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your encounter this error not when your list contains one item but rather when you have no list at all but a plain object, thus the parser complains about a misplaced `START_OBJECT` token.
To remedy this and without being able to edit Swagger-generated domain classes, you could set the deserialization feature

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // maybe injected
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

directly on the `ObjectMapper` that you are using.

This object mapper can now be put into the `RestTemplate` config:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class JsonControllerIT {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void jsonWithSerializationFeatureSet() {
        // given
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(m -> m.getClass().getName().equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class.getName()));
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(messageConverter);

        // when
        Detail detail = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/json", Detail.class).getBody();

        // then
        assertThat(detail.getSingleItemList().get(0)).isEqualTo(3);
    }
}
```

If you use the Spring-approach keep in mind that you also can inject all those beans, they are created here straight-forward just show them better together.

You can also check this running example:

- https://github.com/mle-enso/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/test/java/de/mle/stackoverflow/jackson/JsonControllerIT.java
- https://github.com/mle-enso/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/main/java/de/mle/stackoverflow/jackson/JsonController.java

Comment: I am calling   restTemplate.getForEntity("someurl", Detail.class).getBody();
I am not using objectMapper anywhere. Where do I get access to this ObjectMapper in order to set this value and how would this setting get applied to the GET/post? Maybe I am missing some concept. Can you explain more?

Comment: I just tried something like (it does NOT fix my problem) :    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = template.getMessageConverters().stream()
                .filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
                .map(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::cast)
                .findFirst().orElseThrow( () -> new RuntimeException("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = messageConverter.getObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example how to put your configured `ObjectMapper` into a `RestTemplate`. Have fun!

Comment: I tried this and I got rid of that error. However, it seem to have another side effect. I use this template for other operations like post, patch etc too. so with this change, I start getting another error with the post, patch - "HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "status" (class com.abc.mytest.model.Product), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:   I am not getting any clue on what is causing this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have different requirements regarding the deserialization config, you have either to use different different RestTemplates and the other one for example with `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);` to ignore unknown fields. You can also put this deserialization feature on the one and only RestTemplate if you want to ignore unknown fields during all your deserialization.Or you can put an `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on your `Product` class to ignore unknown fields.

Comment: But, how do I put @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on the Product class when its a swagger generated class?

Comment: You're right, adding this annotation was more or less an informative hint, consider it another option in general. So no problem, just add this `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to your object mapper as described in my last comment.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way other than maintain 2 restTemplates? Also, what is the exact reason of that 'Unrecognized field error'? I dont get that error when doing Post, patch etc without setting mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);  Only after setting it, I start getting that error as if its a side effect of that setting

Comment: The reason for an "Unrecognized field error" is that in your response body exists a field which can not be mapped to a field in your Java class (I assume `Detail`). You do not have to separate the templates by necessity, ignoring unknown fields is IMHO a good practice to be more resilient of payloads which you do not have completely under your control. The "Unrecognized field "status"" for your `Product` seems to me another issue. Suggestion: Let's finish this one here as your original problem was fixed and instantly open a new question with more information about the fields ins your `Product`